# How dispatch function with Redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I try dispatch function with Redux-thunk, but get error ***Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions***

index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { App } from './components/App'
import reducer from './services/store/reducer';


const store = createStore(reducer,
  compose(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

action

```
export const getTicketsData = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoadingStatus());
    const { searchId } = await getSearchID();
    dispatch(setSearchID(searchId));
    try {
        const { tickets, stop } = await getTickets(searchId);
        dispatch(addTicketsData(tickets));
        dispatch(setLoadedStatus());
        dispatch(allTicketsLoaded(stop));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch(serverError());
    }
}
```

component

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getTicketsData());
    }, []);
```

I don't understand, help please

Comment: Do you have all the imports you need in index.js? Where do `createStore`, `compose`, and `applyMiddleware` come from? Assuming you're importing them all correctly, I can't spot any obvious mistake anywhere. The thunk and how you dispatch it all looks correct.

Comment: Yes, I have all imports.
And this is problem, where mistake I don't see it

Comment: Please comment out all the other `dispatch` calls within that thunk. I assume one of them accidentally returns`undefined` or something like that from their action creator.

Comment: I use this code in component and didn't have errors

`useEffect(async () => {
        dispatch(setListStatus('loading'));
        const { searchId } = await getSearchID();
        dispatch(setSearchID(searchId));
        try {
            const { tickets, stop } = await getTickets(searchId);
            dispatch(addTicketsData(tickets));
            dispatch(setListStatus('loaded'));
            dispatch(allTicketsLoaded(stop));
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(serverError());
        }
   }, []);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in index.js need change **applyMiddleware** <->  **window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS...**

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers(rootReducer()),
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
)
```